# Convert to bytes from jpeg in java

Tags: java, byte, jpeg, bufferedimage

I want to convert byte array from JPEG in Java. Below code makes wrong my request.

```
BufferedImage img=Image.read("C:\blabla");
WritableRaster raster=img.getRaster();
DataBufferByte buffer=(DataBufferByte)raster.getDataBuffer();
byte[] jpegbytes=buffer.getData();
```

When I execute it gives wrong byte number. JPEG has size 845.941 bytes on disk.  But, it returns size 2 359 296 bytes in `jpegbytes`. How can I get to correct byte value? I think, `BufferedImage` class gets take wrong.

Comment: Jpegs are compressed data. If you think the jpeg is the "correct size" get the file size and don't read the image to a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: What `Image` class are you using? I don't see any `read` method in the [JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html)

Comment: @4castle the class is `javax.imageio.ImageIO`, I guess the OP made a typo.

Comment: ı dont know. only ı want to convert  bytes from jpeg without losing. then ı will save to  on .bin  format in disk

Comment: @fabian  how can i read bytes of file ?

Comment: @4castle why method can i use ? for without losing bytes.

Comment: With `FileInputStream`. Your question confuses the size of a JPEG file with the size of an image. The image is no longer a JPEG after you load it, it is an image,and it has been decompressed.

Comment: What you do seems correct. You may mistaken the size on disk with the image dimensions. The size on disk (estimated in number of byte) is lower than the real number of byte (equal to width x height x channels) because jpg compresses an image.

Comment: ı want to read from a url. and convert to bytes then save to disk .bin format ? @fabian

Answer (score 2):

You can write any file to a byte array by writing the contents of its FileInputStream to a ByteArrayOutputStream and calling toByteArray().

```
public byte[] fileToBytes(String filename) throws IOException {
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filename))) {
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```